# Laravel. Пагинация изменяет параметр page в url, но не меняет страницу

Tags: mysql, laravel, bootstrap, pagination

При переключении меняется только параметр page в url адресе. Offset в дебагере остаётся тем же.

select * from `notifications` order by `id` desc limit 3 offset 0 (вторая страница)

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example2_paginate">
         <ul class="pagination">
             {{ $notifications->links() }}
         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NotificationController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $notifications = Notification::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    return view('admin.notifications.index', compact('notifications'));
}
```

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot(): void
{
   Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Значения в переменной **$notifications**

[image: $notification]

Comment: Проблема решена. Проблема была в nginx. Замените **try_files $uri /index.php** на **try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string**